# i want to know what are all the triggers available for treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, treeview

i want to know what are all the triggers available for treeview.I want to change the color of selected item in treeview. Any answers plzz..

Answer (score 3):

You can see a list of all the WPF treeview's members on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview_members.aspx

Comment: I had given selectedItem as property for trigger but it is showing the error that SelectedItem is not there. what to do for that.